# How to run Scrapy project in Jupyter?

Tags: python, scrapy, jupyter

On a Mac, I have Jupyter installed and when I type `jupyter notebook` from the root folder of my Scrapy project, it opens the notebook. I can browse all of the project files at this point.

How do I execute the project from the notebook?

If I click the Running tab, under Terminals, I see:

```
There are no terminals running.
```

Answer (score 16):

There are two main ways to achieve that:

1.
Under the *Files* tab open a new terminal: *New > Terminal*
Then simply run you spider: `scrapy crawl [options] <spider>`

2.
Create a new notebook and use `CrawlerProcess` or `CrawlerRunner` classes to run in a cell:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl('your-spider')
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

[Scrapy docs - Run Scrapy from a script](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)

Answer (score 9):

No Need of Terminal to run Spyder Class. Just add the following code in your `jupyter-notebook` cell:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

For more information see [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)

Answer (score 2):

Jupyter has a shortcut to run command line arguments from a cell itself. Start the cell with `!` and type rest of the command as you normally would in console.

[Read More](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html)